# How to save TextView/Array in Android and Retrieve it later?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I am really new to this and making steady progress in regards to making an application. I want to create an app that allows the user to generate a random password using a slider to set the length and then have it generate. Once this is done I would like the user to be able to save their generated passwords. So far I have achieved everything apart from saving the passwords to be restored later after the app has been closed. I have read many posts and I just cant understand how to save application data after the app has closed, weather it be to a file or SharedPrefrences. Some clarification and help would be very much appreciated.

**What I want to Achieve**

I would like a button that the user clicks and the passwords they have generated (that are stored in that array) are saved in the app then when they close it and come back later they can retrieve those saved passwords.

Thanks to everyone in advanced, I do beg my pardon regarding the code its probably very messy but I am learning :D

Thanks

-Jack

**[MainActivity Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6sQV.png)**

**Main Activity XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.jrfapplications.passgen.MainActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passdesc"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:max="20"
        android:progress="10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/passbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:onClick="genpass"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/SeekValueView"
        android:id="@+id/SeekTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/pass_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pass_desc_size"
        android:id="@+id/passdesc"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:textSize="@dimen/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/NextPageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="goToSavedPassActivity"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity Java:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView mPassword;
    Button mGenPassButton;      //Defining Variables
    final TextView mSeekBarValue;
    Button mSavedPassActivity;

    mPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mGenPassButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);        //Settings values and locations
    mSeekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SeekTextView);
    SeekBar seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    mSavedPassActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() { //Seekbar Actions

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) { //When user moves it
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SeekBarValue.seekval = progress;
            mSeekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

        }
    });

    mSavedPassActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SavedPassActivity.class));
        }
    });

    mGenPassButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".toCharArray();
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < SeekBarValue.seekval; i++) {
                char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                sb.append(c);
            }

            final String output = sb.toString();
            mPassword.setText(output);
            SavedPassArray.SavedPasswords.add(output);
        }
    });

    }
}
```

**SeekBarValue Java:**

```
    public class SeekBarValue {
public static int seekval;
}
```

**SavedPassedArray Java:**

```
    public class SeekBarValue {
public static int seekval;
}
```

**[ViewPasswordActivity ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv2pr.png)**

**Password View Activity XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_saved_pass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.jrfapplications.passgen.SavedPassActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/PassList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PasswordsList"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Password View Java:**

```
public class SavedPassActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_pass);

    final TextView mPasswordsLists;

    mPasswordsLists = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PasswordsList);

    StringBuilder allpasswords = new StringBuilder();

    for (String s : SavedPasswords ){
        if(allpasswords.length() > 0){
            allpasswords.append("\n");
        }
        allpasswords.append(s);        }

    mPasswordsLists.setText(allpasswords.toString());
    mPasswordsLists.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    //for(int i=0; i < SavedPasswords.size(); i++){
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a database. Lists in SharedPreferences don't work so well. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the data in `SharedPreferences`

//Creating a shared preference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = getSharedPreferences("User", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
prefsEditor.putString("User", Name);
prefsEditor.putString("Password", password);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

here,`Name` is a veriable contains the username,veriable `password` contains the password to be stored

To read data

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("User", MODE_PRIVATE);
String Name = prefs.getString("Name", null);
String password = prefs.getString("Password", null);
```

null is important, if the entry `Name` don't exists, then it will return null.If you put "Guest" instead of null,then it will return "Guest" when the `Name` not exists.

Comment: This is a fine solution for one user and one password, but I believe the question asked about saving multiple. You could instead make the username the key and the password the value, I guess

Comment: Thats gud !!  But,  In the screenshot there is no option for entering the name.So make a unique ID for each users, eg. user01, user02 ...   And show all usernames with password when clicking the VIEW PASSWORDS Button

Comment: Okay, the user key is always the same. Still, storing a list of potentially infinite strings isn't how SharedPreferences should be used

Comment: Thanks!   Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use Json,

create JsonObeject like this,

```
    try {
        JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
        user.put("Id","Id of the user");
        user.put("Name","name of the user");
        user.put("Password","password for the user");  
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

then add each users to a jsonArray

```
    try {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("Id","Id of the user");
        object.put("Name","name of the user");
        object.put("Password","password for the user");

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        array.put(object);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can save the array in SharedPreferences

//Creating a shared preference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = getSharedPreferences("User", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
prefsEditor.putString("Users", array.toString());
prefsEditor.commit();
```

To read the array

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("User", MODE_PRIVATE);
String arrayString = prefs.getString("Users", null);
```

to convert the string to jsonArray

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(arrayString);
```

here you can display all users with id, name and password like this

```
try {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject user = array.getJSONObject(i);

        textViewId.setText(user.getString("Id"));
        textViewName.setText(user.getString("Name"));
        textViewPassword.setText(user.getString("Password"));
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can search the user with Id like this,

```
try {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject user = array.getJSONObject(i);

        if (user.getString("Id").equals("Required Id")) {

            textViewId.setText(user.getString("Id"));
            textViewName.setText(user.getString("Name"));
            textViewPassword.setText(user.getString("Password"));
            break;
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can search the user with Name like this,

```
try {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject user = array.getJSONObject(i);

        if (user.getString("Name").equals("Required Name")) {

            textViewId.setText(user.getString("Id"));
            textViewName.setText(user.getString("Name"));
            textViewPassword.setText(user.getString("Password"));
            break;
        }
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used this method but I still thank you for the information :)